# Different result in Visual Studio 2019 and Linux

Tags: c++

My code works perfectly in visual studio and Linux but i encounter a problem running it in Linux.
The function is about a dynamic array with a header file. 
When I input number N, it prints prime numbers between 2 and N 
Output:
I got only prime numbers under 10, when I used Linux.
Same code but different result!!
Please help me to know how I can get it fixed.
This is a part of the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sieve.h"
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//prints all the prime numbers between 2 and N

Sieve::Sieve()
{
    cout << "Enter the number of integers to input: ";
    cin >> N;
    arr = new bool[N + 1];
    memset(arr, true, sizeof(arr));
    
    for (int p = 2; p * p <= N; p++)
    {
        if (arr[p] == true)
        {
            for (int i = p * p; i <= N; i += p)
                arr[i] = false;
        }

    }

    return;
}

void Sieve::show()
{
    cout << "Following are the prime numbers between 2 and "
         << N << endl;

    for (int p = 2; p <= N; p++)
        if (arr[p])
            cout << p << " ";

    cout << endl;
}

Sieve::~Sieve()
{
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `sizeof(arr)`?

Comment: [Zero Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) could make your life easier here.

Comment: @vll Thank you so much. I didn't know how to use "memset". Actually, I'm not sure even now, so I replaced it with "for" loop.

Comment: If it hasn't been forbidden, consider using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for `arr`. It handles allocation, deallocation, initialization, and the utterly vital [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for you.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` yields the size of `bool*`, not the size of `bool[N]`. Furthermore using `std::fill_n` makes for code that is imho easier to understand `std::fill_n(arr, N+1, true);`

Comment: `memset(arr, true, sizeof(arr));` -- For a laugh, make `N` equal to 1000, and then  `arr = new bool[N + 1]; std::cout << sizeof(arr);` and observe the results.   You will see what everyone has mentioned.  You will see that the output is either going to be 4 or 8.  It won't be 1000, or whatever you expected it to be.

Comment: Small caveat I didn't think about earlier: `std::vector<bool>` is a weird sucker. So weird that it [typically gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). It's very space efficient, but doesn't behave the same as other `vector`s and can be a little slow (a trade-off for the space efficiency). Often people make a `vector` of bytes or similar to keep the size small (but not as small as `vector<bool>`) and get the behaviours they expect.

Answer (score 2):

`memset` comes from C, and is generally incompatible with `bool`. It sets the memeory to a bitpattern, specifically `static_cast<unsigned char>(true)`. There's no gurantee that `static_cast<unsigned char>(true)` has the same bitpattern as `true`.

`std::fill` works with pretty much any element type and any container.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(arr)` would never be equal to size of your allocated array. It would be equal to `sizeof(bool*)` if `arr` is a pointer or if `arr` is some compound  type that accepts pointer assignment, it's some different value, just never right one ...

Do not use `memset` for `bool`s. On some platform true might have "all ones" binary pattern, on other it is just 1, `sizeof(bool)` may vary from 1 to 4 bytes. Use range-base filling (e.g. std::fill or plain for-loop), where `arr` would be the "begin" of the range and `arr + N + 1` would be the "end".